# How to get updated row's PK_ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to get updated row's PK_ID

```
UPDATE 
    [M_RATINGS] 
SET 
    [RATING] = @rating 
WHERE 
    [POST_ID] = @postId AND 
    [USER_ID] = @userId;
```

Comment: Which IDs are you using to update? Use those to get PKId

Comment: I want to know updated row's primary key(PK_ID)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use OUTPUT clause http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(
ID int NOT NULL
); 

UPDATE 
   [M_RATINGS] 
SET   
   [RATING] = @rating 
OUTPUT INSERTED.YourPK_ID INTO @MyTableVar
WHERE 
   [POST_ID] = @postId AND 
   [USER_ID] = @userId;
```

SELECT * from @MyTableVar;

Comment: Like this?

UPDATE 
     [M_RATINGS] 
SET 
     [RATING] = @rating 
OUTPUT
 [PK_ID]
WHERE 
    [POST_ID] = @postId AND 
    [USER_ID] = @userId;

Comment: @Michael 
But it is showing..
Incorrect syntax near 'OUTPUT'.

Comment: @Venom, what is version of your DBMS?

Comment: @Venom, when you said 'non working', what so you mean? Syntax error or something else?

Comment: @Venom, I really hope that you changed YourPK_ID to your real column name which used as primary key in table M_RATINGS.